# How can i traverse to particular key dynamically in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Probelm statement:

```
response= [{'HotelId': 8, 'IsFast': False, 'Payload': {'HotelInstaceId': 8, 'IsResetNeeded': False, 'HotelType': 'test', 'Product': {'Family': 'Times', 'Model': 'Roman', 'Type': 'Visible', 'Vendor': 'Royal'}, 'Hotel': {'DisplayBrightness': 80, 'LedColor': None, 'Location': '', 'Name': 'testing'}}}]
```

I want to verify the value of name "testing".

My code:

```
result = response["Data"][0]["Payload"]["Name"]
if result == "testing":
   print("pass")
else:
   print("fail")
```

New code:

```
tests = [{'a': 1},
         {'b': {'a': 2}},
         {'a': 3, 'b': {'a': 4}},
         {'a': {'b': 5}},
         {'a': {'a': 6}}]
def recursively_find_dict_values(self, d, tests, key="HotelType"):
    output = []
    for i, v in d.items():
        if i == key:
            output.append(v)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            output.extend(self.recursively_find_dict_values(v, key, tests))
    return output

for t in tests:
    recursively_find_dict_values(t, key="HotelType")
```

i will get the response from another function and that response i will send to "recursively_find_dict_values" func as a argument..

Example inputs:

```
Input keys                            Output 

 "Name"                               "testing"
 "DisplayBrightness"                   80
 "HotelType"                           "test"
```

but i want to do in generic way like if i pass "Name" or "DisplayBrightness" or any key to the function it should return the value and also if keys in nested dictionary then also it should return the value.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What do you want the function to do if the key is (through nested dictionaries) in a dictionary multiple times? Raise an error, or return a list of values?

Comment: Also, could you provide an some example inputs and the associated desired outputs for the function? I think your description of generic key finding is a bit unclear, and doesn't appear to relate directly to the example.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want, but you may want to consider using a chainmap:, https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap.

Comment: One more question: what if the input key has a dict as a value (e.g. `d = {1: {2: 'b'}, 3: 'c'}; find_value_from_dict(d, 1)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be able to help you:

```
def recursively_find_dict_values(d, key):
    output = []
    for i,v in d.items():
        if i == key:
            output.append(v)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            output.extend(recursively_find_dict_values(v, key))
    return output

tests = [{'a': 1},
         {'b': {'a': 2}},
         {'a': 3, 'b': {'a': 4}},
         {'a': {'b': 5}},
         {'a': {'a': 6}}]

for t in tests:
    print(recursively_find_dict_values(t, 'a'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDRisIwEHzPV@xbWwjC6Z0PQr9EpMRmi8tpGpJNuCL99l5jhCoU9yGQnZndmbUDX3qzmyaNHThsg/MU8To0HRndaGq5ieoa0Jdawi8O1UHAXH1gGxhqOJ4e/653QDICGdAbYrz58slMRR0Q1HXSL81lzEZZi0aXsXpTeDKelWmxjBKSk2pVjH@cxB@9x@w9z3fIwZmnXAhGzz4luReqOMDXKJct9@I8tzKwHd@R1NtJeGF8rzDyhJ9VJL37cTwJkc7H6XgPMzmmdWT4cyye16tijjVN/w)

I would check all the examples to see if the functionality is to your liking. Note that if the value of `'a'` is a dict, it will add a dict to the list, and if the dict value of `'a'` *also* has a key `'a'`, both levels will be added to the dict (see the fifth example). Also, even if there is only one match, it will still return a list.

---

In this example, d is the name of your input dict:

```
# Getting all the values of key in d:

values = recursively_find_dict_values(d, key)

# Checking if key has value v in d:

if v in recursively_find_dict_values(d):
    print('Success!')
```

Comment: @sai If the question is on topic according to the [help/on-topic] for Stack Overflow, you can ask it here. Also, I would recommend reading [ask] before asking it. If it's just a direct extension of this question, you can edit this question.

Comment: Just do `recursively_find_dict_values(input_dict, 'tests')`

Comment: Or do you want the function to be able to handle multiple arguments? That would require modification of the function...

Comment: I'm confused. Are you planning to use this function as a class method? And what does `ws_response` do?

Comment: Are you trying to see if a dict has a key recursively with a specific value? If so you want to use this as your checking condition `'tests' in recursively_find_dict_values(input_dict, key)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I thought my earlier comment answered that question. Could you edit your question to provide another ([mcve]) example of what you mean?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. The tests were just an example to show how it works; you don't need them for the function. I'll edit my answer to show what I mean. Also, unless this is a class method, the first parameter doesn't need to be `self`.

Comment: It's not working...Could you please update your function itself. I tried and it's not working.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you don't update your question to explain in more detail, I can't help you. If you don't like the list output, you could always just get the first element of the list if the list only has one element. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean when you say it's not working.